# Cryptographically secure number generator for node.js

Tags: random, node.js

I am looking for a cryptographically secure number generator for node.js. Afaik. `Math.random()` does not meet these requirements. Is there any nodejs lib which can generate cryptographically secure numbers?

Comment: Are you looking for [a true random number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_vs._pseudo-random_numbers), or just [a psuedo-random number generator that's cryptographically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator)?  Anyways, product recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Can you first explain what your requirements are and what about `Math.random()` does not meet those requirements?  You have not described your actual requirements so we can't really know what would be needed for your solution.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov Cryptographically secure is enough if true random is not possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct that `Math.random()` is not secure. If you want a [CSPRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) in Node.js, [`crypto.randomBytes()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> There are a few libs available, but I need to be certain whether they are really true random.

*Any one who considers arithmetical methods of producing random digits is, of course, in a state of sin.*

Basically, no library can generate any "really true random"s. Lately some processors include support for hardware RNGs, which allows (hopefully) "really true random"s to be generated.

That being said, there are -very- few applications for which a CSPRNG will not suffice. In fact, CSPRNGs offer such good quality randomness that I can't think of any.

Comment: Thanks! Then it was a misunderstanding. What I meant is cryptographically secure instead of true random.

Comment: I edited the question.